# Converting NSDate to String gets empty object

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsdate

In the app, there is a screen in which I use a `Date Picker` in mode `Date` to get the date input.

Then this screen will pass the date input in `NSDate` type to the previous screen to display as `textFiled` after a conversion to string.

```
func dateDetector(aDate: UIDatePicker) {

    let dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormat.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
    dateFormat.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle

    dueDate = aDate.date
```

Comment: Side note: could you please *stop* using "Xcode" as a tag and in your question titles? You did it for many of your last questions, where none of them are related to Xcode. You're using Xcode - you're not asking anything about it. Let's just focus on the actual topic. Thanks. :)

Comment: Please provide a minimal example with exact values. This question takes a lot of time to decipher.

Comment: whats wrong :)) Swift not relates to Xcode then Swift relates to Android Studio :))

Comment: Tags are not about what the question relates to, but what the question is about. By the same logic you can just pick a random tag and find some kind of relation

Comment: What's going wrong? You should tell us. We can tell you what is causing a problem, but not what the problem is. You tell us what is happening and compare that with what you want to happen. Then we can help you find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the answer added by ryantxr

Sometimes you need to set a locale identifier when you are storing a date and retrieving it.
Eg:-

{

```
let dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
dateFomat.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"en_IN")
dateFormat.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
dateFormat.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle

dueDate = aDate.date
```

}

when changing to string
{

`let dateFormat = NSDateFormatter() 
   dateFomat.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"en_IN")
   dateFomat.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
   let datestring = dteformat.stringFromDate(dueDate)`

}

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not give the formatter a style.

```
let df = NSDateFormatter()
df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
let ds = df.stringFromDate(nsd)

print(ds)
```

If you don't give it a style you will get an empty string.